# Does the free ASEZA visa allow to travel outside Aqaba?

Tags: visas, jordan

I understand that if I arrive to Jordan through Aqaba I can get a one month free visa with the condition to leave the country through one of the 3 Aqaba borders (Saudi Arabia, ferry to Egypt or international flight). But I want to visit the whole country, not only Aqaba. Does the free ASEZA visa allow me to travel to Petra, Wadi Rum and other places across Jordan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This free visa entitles you to travel all around Jordan for 1 month, but you will have to leave via the same border point you entered at.

From [Go2Jordan.info](http://www.your-guide-to-aqaba-jordan.com/visa_to_jordan.html).